# How to draw MA horizontal lines in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

```
dma120=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D",ta.sma(close,120))
plot(dma120, color= color.blue, title = "D MA120" )

h4ma30=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240",ta.sma(close,30))
plot(h4ma30, color= color.red, title = "4H MA30" )

hline(3.14, title='Pi', color=color.blue, linestyle=hline.style_dotted, linewidth=2)
```

In this way, it can only plot the lines, and it is impossible to use the value of the MA to the HLINE function.

It is displayed in whole layout by using Hline function, but I don't want it in that way. I want it achieved the result that I attached on the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using `line` from [drawings](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html).

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", max_lines_count=1, overlay=true)

dma120=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ta.sma(close,120))
plot(dma120, color= color.blue, title = "D MA120" )

var line l_dma120 = line.new(bar_index, dma120, bar_index+1, dma120, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow)

if barstate.islast
    line.set_xy1(l_dma120, bar_index, dma120)
    line.set_xy2(l_dma120, bar_index+1, dma120)
```

Blue line is the `plot`, and yellow line is the `line`.

[image]